# Suppose $A\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is linear and $\ker⁡(A)=\{0\}$.Show that $\|Ax\|\geq \varepsilon \|x\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Suppose $A\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is linear and $\ker⁡(A)=\{0\}$.Show that there exists $\varepsilon >0 $ such that $\|Ax\|\geq \varepsilon \|x\|$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: You may take $\epsilon=\min\{\lVert Ax\rVert\,:\, x\in S^{n-1}\}$.

Answer (score 4):

$x\to \lVert Ax\rVert$ is continuous on $S_{n-1} = \{x\in \mathbb R^n | \lVert x\rVert  = 1\}$, which is a compact set.
So it has a minimum $\epsilon$, which is attained on $x^\star \in S_{n-1}$.
$\epsilon =\lVert Ax^\star\rVert > 0$, since $\operatorname{Ker}(A)= {0}$.

Then for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$,
$$\lVert Ax\rVert = \left\lVert A\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert}\right\rVert \cdot  \lVert x\rVert \geq \epsilon \lVert x\rVert,$$
since $x /{\lVert x\rVert}\in S_{n-1}$ .

Comment: You mean $\|x\|=1$!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for the heads up!